# Unwanted Blank Pages Caused by \chapter*{} and flushleft Commands

Tags: lyx, tex2lyx

I have a Lyx document that consists of a master document and 7 child documents. When I compile it an unwanted blank page is inserted before each chapter. Exporting to Latex I have the following code of interest. The commands that appear to be causing the problem are the \chapter*{} and the pair of flushleft commands, i.e., when these are removed the latex compiles to the desired result. I can't figure out what option in Lyx is inserting these commands. Any ideas?

```
\begin{document}

\chapter*{}

\begin{flushleft}
\par\end{flushleft}

\include{Chapter_1}
\begin{flushleft}
\par\end{flushleft}

\include{Chapter_2}
\begin{flushleft}
\par\end{flushleft}

\include{Chapter_3}
\begin{flushleft}
\par\end{flushleft}

\include{Chapter_4}
\begin{flushleft}
\par\end{flushleft}

\include{Chapter_5}
\begin{flushleft}
\par\end{flushleft}

\include{Chapter_6}
\begin{flushleft}
\par\end{flushleft}

\printbibliography

\appendix

\include{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\chapter` openings are always on an odd (right hand) page by default, if you wat to allow them to be on the left page as well use `\documentclass[popenany]{book}`

Comment: The suggestion in the comment by @DavidCarlisle is the same as what I would suggest, but this seems like a misfeature by Lyx.  There shouldn't be any need for such shenanigans.

Comment: I tried openany but it did not get rid of the blank pages. The only thing that worked was exporting to latex and deleting the commands as described. I can complete the dissertation that way, but I will first spend some time hunting for the origin of those unwanted commands in Lyx.

Comment: @barbarabeeton LyX does not add foolishly flushleft environments with `\chapter*{}` but sadly make a new environment for each paragraph when the user add manually a left align for some text. If some paragraph is later splitted, the enviroment is splitted also automatically. I am unsure if this is a bug or a feature in the mind of developers, but most problably the user wrongly disseminated manually that environments in the main and/or child files. This can be fixed just selecting  all text and returning  to the paragrah's defult.

Comment: If anyone feels like opening a bug report/ feature enhancement at https://www.lyx.org/trac with a  minimal example .lyx file that would be great!

Comment: I checked and there are no left aligns in anything I have written. I am using a document class written by a professor at my university for dissertations. It is based on the memoir class, and has worked perfectly in Lyx except for this blank page problem. I suspect the problem originates in the class definition. Given that I can finish my dissertation by exporting to Latex and the professor is unlikely to be interested in modifying the class to work in Lyx, I will move on. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the parent document I have Lyx comments (the yellow ones) describing the parent and child documents. When I remove these comments the blank pages go away.